# Writing B[49345]=A[3][i-j] in Mips assembly code

Tags: assembly, mips

`B[49345]=A[3][i-j]`
assuming `i` and `j` are in register `$s0` and `$s1` respectively, how do I write an efficient MIPS assembly code corresponding to this expression?
My implementation is as such

```
sll $t0,$s0,2
sub $t0,$t0,$s1
sll $t0,2
lw $t1,12($t0)
add $t1,$s2,$t0
lw $t1,12($t0)
li $t2,49345
sll $t2,2
add $s3,$s3,$t2
sw $t1,0($s3)
```

Declaration of arrays:

`int A[5][20];` 
`int B[50000];`

please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Ask a compiler: https://godbolt.org/  - use MIPS GCC with `-O3` for a function that takes args.  Also, what types to `A` and `B` have?  Apparently `A` is an array of pointers-to-int like `int **A` rather than a 2D array (`int A[][N]`), since your asm has 2 loads.

Comment: But wait, your second load doesn't depend on the result of the first load, it just overwrites it.  Is that for debugging or something, to see some other array value?  Your code makes no sense.

Comment: If you want a decent answer, provide more details, specifically the declarations of `A`, and `B`.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I was curious if GCC or clang would infer that `i-j` must be `0` from `int A[][1]` (which as we discussed in comments under your answer, would make the byte offset of `12` in the OP's code make sense).  No, they don't, they just sub and use the index. https://godbolt.org/z/Yrvr4jKTG  .  MIPS GCC shows how to fold parts of constants into immediates for `lw` and `sw`, e.g. using `sw   $2,772($5)` after adding `0x30000` to the base address of `B` (the high 16 of `49345*sizeof(int) = 0x30304`)

Comment: The question can be salvaged by including the array declarations, though without them, I don't think it is possible to give a decent answer.

Comment: The details have been kindly added please review your minus, And reopen my question Thankyou.

Comment: Now it's at least answerable.  If you're asking about efficiency, it would be better if your asm was  correct.  If you want help understanding why your current code is wrong, it would be better if you included comments showing what you think it does and why.  (If you understand 2D C arrays, the process of re-reading and commenting your asm will hopefully reveal some of what's wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

- You're computing `i*4-j`, which is not the stated C expression, it literally wants `i-j` — that subexpression, `i-j`, has higher precedence than any implicit scaling, so must be computed before (and as the input to) scaling.
- For a two dimensional array, since this is a rectangular array, there is only one (memory access) load necessary, the rest is all address calculation.

  With `int A[5][20]` we have 5 rows of `20*sizeof(int)=80` bytes per row.  Thus, A[3] refers to the base address of the array + `80*3` bytes along — then index past that by the `i-j` scaled amount.

  If both indexes were variable expressions (instead of one being constant), we might compute `(20*3 + i-j)*4` so as to scale (`*4`) only once as the end of the index computation.  However, since the first index is constant we can refactor ([distribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))) as `20*3*4 + (i-j)*4 = 240 + (i-j)*4`.  The reason to do this is that we can use the 240 (in the place where you're using 12).  So, compute `(i-j)*4 + base` and then use 240 as the offset in the `lw`.
- We have to know what registers refer to `A` and `B`, or else simply load them into registers, you didn't say and also didn't load them but I guess we should infer `$s2` and `$s3` from your code.
- If we assume that `B` is in `$s3` then you're altering that, which may or may not be ok, but if I was an instructor I'd point it out.  You're computing `B = B+49345*4` (aka `B += 49345*4`) — where I'm using `B` to mean `$s3` — so `$s3` no longer refers to `B[0]`, which could mess up subsequent code in that same function if any relies on `$s3` to access/index array `B`.  Suggest computing that index plus base sum to a new/different register (and using it in the `sw`), so you can leave `$s3` unmodified.

  When dealing with code snippets smaller than a whole function, it is best not to assume too much about surrounding code and should probably consider that you are not free to modify parameters or given registers, so this would apply to registers for `i`, `j`, `A`, and `B`.  In the context of a complete compile-able function, we could know for sure if we are free to overwrite these registers, by looking further ahead in the function for uses of these variables.

---

Possible Optimization

- You have a 4 instruction sequence to store into `B` as in the assignment `B[49345]=`.  As Peter says, we can shorten by one instruction by using the offset of the `sw` instruction — with each load and store instruction on MIPS we get a free addition of a smallish constant (so we use it when we can and use 0 when we cannot find an appropriate smallish constant).

  One way to do this is compute the value `49345*4 = 197,380 = 0x00030304`, then split that into two 16-bit halves and use the upper 16-bit half (0x0003) in an `lui` instruction and the lower 16-bit half (0x0304 = 772 base 10) in the `sw` instruction.  The `lui` using 0x0003 as immediate, simply loads 0x00030000 into some temporary register (your choice).  Then add the base of `B` from `$s3`, then using `sw` store the value you want to write into memory, using the register you picked, and the low 16-bit value 0x0304 aka 772.  This is then a 3 instruction sequence, `lui`, `addu`, `sw`.

  (The astute reader may realize that the constant for `lw` and `sw` is sign extended so if the 16-bit immediate used is negative, we have to offset the constant used in `lui` by 1 so that the addition of -1 from sign extension will result in the desired address.  This is not an issue here since the constants used in `lw` and `sw` are both positive as 16-bit immediates.

  For example, doing the same indexing with slightly different constant, 32704 as B[32704], we get 32704*4 = 130,816 = 0x0001FF00, so the high half is 0x0001 and low half is 0xFF00.  When the low half is used by `lw` or `sw`, that 16-bit immediate value, 0xFF00 will sign extend causing a -1 to be summed to the upper half, so that upper half needs to be offset by 1, as in 0x0001 + 1 = 0x0002 for the `lui` to address the proper location when the 0xFF00 is used later by the load or store.)

Comment: (Deleted my previous comment since the 2nd load *isn't* dependent on the first.  `$t1` is overwritten without being used.  So you're right, the first `lw` simply doesn't belong.  None of it makes much sense, though, since we aren't told the array dimension if it is `int A[][N]`, and `12` is the wrong byte offset for the first index to be 3 unless it's `int A[][1]`.  In which case `i==j` is the only possibility that isn't UB, so we could assume it.  I'm more inclined to think that's another bug in the OP's code, not something to reverse-engineer from. )

Comment: Address math should always use `addu`, so `lui`/`addu`/`sw`.  But yes, good explanation of how to save an instruction by folding the low half of `0x00030304` into the offset of `sw`, like the OP did with `lw` (except they used the wrong offset)